# Namespaces preventing transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces, saxon, xliff

I am running the following transformation:

```
java -jar saxon9.jar -it:main -xsl:my.xsl dir="ca-ES"
```

The "ca-ES" contains XLIFF files which have the following root element:

```
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cba="http://www.softcon.de/XML-schema/de.softcon.cba.itembuilder.xliff-supplement"
       version="1.1"
       xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1 xliff-core-1.1.xsd">
```

The transformation uses identical files from a secondary input folder and generates as many structurally identical files as found in the input folder.

If I remove the first namespace (i.e. `xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1"`) from the root (i.e. `xliff`), then the transformation works like a charm. However, if I keep it, then it doesn't work.

The part that is not working is the template that matches `source` in the primary input file and replaces it with the `source` from the secondary input file):

```
<xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', ../@id, doc($secondary-input))/source" />
```

By not working I mean that the `source` from the primary input file is in the output rather than the expected `source` node from the secondary input. So it seems the namespace is getting in the way of the matching.

Looking for solutions I have tried adding the `xpath-default-namespace` attribute on the document element of the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1"
    version="2.0">
```

but then the `source` node from the primary input is kept in the output (that is, it's not replaced with the one from the secondary input).

I have also tried adding this prefix and then using it in the stylesheet to match nodes (e.g. `match="xlf:source"`), but then there is no `source` node at all in the output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xlf="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1"
    version="2.0">
```

I'll be grateful for some tips.

I'm using XSLT 2.0 and saxonb9-1-0-8j.

**UPDATE**

Adding one primary input file sample (named `ca-ES_blabla.xlf`, taken from the folder **ca-ES**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cba="http://www.softcon.de/XML-schema/de.softcon.cba.itembuilder.xliff-supplement" version="1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1 xliff-core-1.1.xsd">
  <file datatype="html" original="project.properties" source-language="ca">
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="MDSD_0" xml:space="default">
        <source>Gestiona les adreces d'interès</source>
        <target>Gestiona les adreces d'interès</target>
        <context-group name="era">
          <context context-type="x-property-id">bookmarkHeaderText</context>
        </context-group>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="7" xml:space="default">
        <source>&lt;b&gt;Sempre rebrà un avís quan arribi a un punt a partir del qual no pugui tornar enrere.&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;</source>
        <target>&lt;b&gt;Sempre rebrà un avís quan arribi a un punt a partir del qual no pugui tornar enrere.&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;</target>
        <prop-group name="item_description">
          <prop prop-type="x-inquiry-nr">4</prop>
          <prop prop-type="x-type">question</prop>
        </prop-group>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
<!-- the xliff document might contain several <file> nodes -->
</xliff>
```

one secondary input file sample (named `en-GB_blabla.xlf`, taken from the folder **en-GB**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cba="http://www.softcon.de/XML-schema/de.softcon.cba.itembuilder.xliff-supplement" version="1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1 xliff-core-1.1.xsd">
  <file datatype="html" original="project.properties" source-language="en-GB">
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="MDSD_0" xml:space="default">
        <source>Manage your bookmarks</source>
        <target>Manage your bookmarks</target>
        <context-group name="era">
          <context context-type="x-property-id">bookmarkHeaderText</context>
        </context-group>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="7" xml:space="default">
        <source>&lt;b&gt;You will always receive a warning before reaching a point where you cannot go back.&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;</source>
        <target>&lt;b&gt;You will always receive a warning before reaching a point where you cannot go back.&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;</target>
        <prop-group name="item_description">
          <prop prop-type="x-inquiry-nr">4</prop>
          <prop prop-type="x-type">question</prop>
        </prop-group>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
<!-- the xliff document might contain several <file> nodes -->
</xliff>
```

and the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1‌​.1"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- run as: 
    $> java -jar saxon9.jar -it:main -xsl:this_stylesheet.xsl dir="xx-XX"      -->

    <!-- this captures the folder parameter given in the call -->  
    <xsl:param name="dir" select="dir" />

    <!-- this template iterates through the files in the input folder --> 
    <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:variable name="input-files" select="concat($dir, '?select=*.xlf')" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="collection($input-files)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- this template defines the name of the output folder and files -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="output-name" select="replace(
            tokenize(document-uri(/), '/')[last()], 
            '(.+)\.xlf', 
            '$1_bilingual.xlf'
            )"/>
        <xsl:result-document href="{$dir}_output/{$output-name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- this template fetches the source from the English files --> 
    <xsl:key name="ref" match="trans-unit" use="@id"/> 
    <xsl:template match="source">
        <xsl:variable name="input-uri" select="document-uri(/)" />
        <!-- <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$input-uri" /></xsl:message> -->
        <xsl:variable name="secondary-input" select="replace($input-uri, $dir, 'en-GB')"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', ../@id, doc($secondary-input))/source" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- this part generates the output --> 
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do both input files (primary pulled in with collection and secondary pulled in with doc) use exactly the same namespace?

Comment: Hi Martin :) Yes, primary and secondary input files are identical except for the content of the `source` node.

Comment: You might want to add the stylesheet and two input samples to allow us to debug it if you can't find the problem yourself, I think it must be a namespace difference between the two files.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no difference between in the root nodes between the two input files, I have just compared a few with Oxygen's Diff Files. The only differences are in the content of the source elements and the target-language values. I'm adding them and the stylesheet in a minute to my question.

Comment: I agree those two XML documents use the same default namespace, that means the stylesheet from the earlier question can't work unless you add `xpath-default-namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1"` on the root of the stylesheet. I don't think the stylesheet posted in this question will compile at all, given then use of prefixes `match="xlf:trans-unit"` without declaring it.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The `xlf` prefix was left from my early test with `xmlns:xlf="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1"`, which didn't work either. I've just fixed it in the question. However, as I mentioned, adding the `xpath-default-namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1‌​.1"` doesn't make it work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147131/discussion-between-msoutopico-and-martin-honnen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a namespace problem, when I copy over the value `"urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1"` from the source to the stylesheet as `xpath-default-namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1"` the code works.

I am not sure which characters you have in your stylesheet code (oXygen asked me to enable some language support when pasting your code) but somehow the strings

```
"urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1"
"urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1‌​.1"
```

are not equal:

```js
var s1 = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1";
var s2 = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1‌​.1";
document.writeln('<code>' + s1 + ' === ' + s2 + ' : ' + (s1 === s2) + '<\/code>');
```

It might be that the namespace in your stylesheet contains one or more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner after the first digit `1`.

Comment: To be precise, my xmlns string had a ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER (U+200C) and a ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B). To be honest, I have no clue where they came from, but you are right, removing those extraneous characters the stylesheet works. Thanks, Martin.